# React componet not loading/ not displaying?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I’m trying to navigate to a link /contact-us, when I click the actual link I can see the URL change in the browser but the ContactUs component isn’t loaded:

*/src/app.jsx*

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navBar/navIndex';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Footer from './components/Footer/footer';
import NotFoundView from './components/Error/Error404';
import Contact from './components/ContactUs/Contact';
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/contact-us' element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundView />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*\src\components\navBar\navIndex.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import { Nav1, Nav2, NavLink, Bars, NavMenu, NavBtn, NavBtnLink } from './navBarElements';

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <Nav1>
        <NavLink to='/'>
          <h1>Logo</h1>
        </NavLink>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
          <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/services' activeStyle>
            Services
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/contact-us' activeStyle>
            Contact Us
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
          </NavLink>
          Second Nav
        <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavMenu>
        {/* <NavBtn>
          <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn> */}
      </Nav1>
      <Nav2>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
          <NavLink to='/home' activeStyle>
            Home
          </NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/events' activeStyle>
              Events
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/jobs' activeStyle>
              Jobs
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/accommodations' activeStyle>
              Accommodations
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/discussion' activeStyle>
              Discussions
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/book' activeStyle>
              Books
            </NavLink>
          </NavMenu>
      </Nav2>
    </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

*\src\components\ContactUs\Contact.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import Input from '../FormReuses/Input';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import {Headline, FormWrapper, RowCol1,RowCol2,RowCol3,RowCol4, Column1,Column2,Column3, Column4, Icon, Item, Text, Message} from './ContactElements';
import {FormReuse, Form} from '../FormReuses/FormReuse';
import { FaPhone } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaLocationArrow } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaMailchimp } from "react-icons/fa";


const initialFieldValues = {
    id : 0,
    fullName:'',
    email:'',
    mobileNo:'',
    message:'',
}

export default function Contact() {

    const validation = ()=> {
        let temp = {}
        if (!values.fullName.trim()) {
            temp.fullName="Name required."
        }
        else if (!/^[A-Z a-z]+$/.test(values.fullName)) {
            temp.fullName="Alphabetical letters only."
        }

        // temp.fullName = values.fullName?"":"This field is required."
        if (!values.email) {
            temp.email="Email Required."
        }else if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,4}$/.test(values.email)) {
            temp.email="Invalid Email address."
        }
        //temp.email = (/$|.+@.+..+/).test(values.email)?"":"Email is not valid."
        if (!values.mobileNo) {
            temp.mobileNo="Mobile number required."
        }else if (!/^[0-9]{10,}$/.test(values.mobileNo)) {
            temp.mobileNo="Invalid mobile Number."
        }
        // else if (values.mobileNo.length<9 && /^[0-9]$/i.test(values.mobileNo)) {
        //     temp.mobileNo="Invalid mobile Number."
        // }
        //temp.mobileNo = values.mobileNo.length>9?"":"Mobile number is not valid."
        // temp.message = values.message?"":"This field is required."
        if (!values.message) {
            temp.message="Field required."
        }


        if (!values.eventName) {
            temp.eventName="Name required."
        }
        else if (!/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(values.eventName)) {
            temp.eventName="Alphabetical letters only."
        }
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        })

        return Object.values(temp).every(x => x =="")
    }

    

    

    const{
        values,
        setValues,
        handleInputChange,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        reset
    }=FormReuse(initialFieldValues);

    

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validation())
            window.alert('testing...')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            
        {/* <Main> */}
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormWrapper>
                    <Headline>Event Registration Form</Headline> 
                    <RowCol1>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Event Name"
                                name="eventName"
                                value={values.eventName}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.eventName}

                            />
                        </Column1>
                    </RowCol1>
                    <RowCol2>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Event Organizer"
                                name="eventOrganizer"
                                value={values.eventOrganizer}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.eventOrganizer}

                            />
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <Input
                                label="Event Type"
                                name="eventType"
                                value={values.eventType}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.eventType}
                            />
                        </Column2>
                    </RowCol2>  
                    <RowCol4>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Date"
                                name="date"
                                value={values.date}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.date}

                            />
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <Input
                                label="Start Time"
                                name="startTime"
                                value={values.startTime}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.startTime}

                            />
                        </Column2>
                        <Column3>
                            <Input
                                label="End Time"
                                name="endTime"
                                value={values.endTime}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.endTime}

                            />
                        </Column3>
                        <Column4>
                            <Input
                                label="$Cost/Ticket"
                                name="costPerTicket"
                                value={values.costPerTicket}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.costPerTicket}
                            />
                        </Column4>
                    </RowCol4>
                    <RowCol3>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Venue"
                                name="Venue"
                                value={values.Venue}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.Venue}

                            />
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <Input
                                label="Online Event"
                                name="onlineEvent"
                                value={values.onlineEvent}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.onlineEvent}

                            />
                        </Column2>
                        <Column3>
                            <Input
                                label="TBA"
                                name="tba"
                                value={values.tba}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.tba}

                            />
                        </Column3>
                    </RowCol3>
                    <RowCol1>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Auto Address"
                                name="autoAdd"
                                value={values.autoAdd}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.autoAdd}
                            />
                        </Column1>
                    </RowCol1>
                    <RowCol2>
                        <Column1>
                        <Input
                                label="Buy Ticket"
                                name="buyTicket"
                                value={values.buyTicket}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.buyTicket}
                            />
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <Input
                                label="Refund"
                                name="refund"
                                value={values.refund}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.refund}

                            />
                        </Column2>
                    </RowCol2>
                    <RowCol1>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Description"
                                multiline="true"
                                name="description"
                                rows={5}
                                value={values.description}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.description}
                            />
                        </Column1>    
                    </RowCol1>


    {/* ================================================================================================= */}
                    <Headline>Contact Us</Headline>
                      <RowCol2>
                        <Column1>
                            <Input
                                label="Full Name"
                                name="fullName"
                                value={values.fullName}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.fullName}

                            />
                            <Input
                                label="Email"
                                name="email"
                                value={values.email}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.email}

                            />
                            <Input
                                label="Mobile"
                                name="mobileNo"
                                value={values.mobileNo}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.mobileNo}

                            />
                            <Input
                                label="Message"
                                multiline="true"
                                name="message"
                                rows={5}
                                value={values.message}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                error={errors.message}
                            />
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                size="large"
                                color="secondary"
                                type="submit"
                            >
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                size="large"
                                color="default"
                                type="reset"
                                onClick={reset}
                            >
                                Reset
                            </Button>
                        </Column1>
                        
                        
                        <Column2>
                            
                                <Item>
                                    <Icon><FaLocationArrow fontSize="large" /></Icon>
                                    <Text>Kathmandu, Nepal</Text>
                                </Item>
                                <Item>
                                    <Icon><FaPhone fontSize="large" /></Icon>
                                    <Text>+977-9876543210</Text>
                                </Item>
                                <Item>
                                    <Icon><FaMailchimp fontSize="large" /></Icon>
                                    <Text>Mailme@gmail.com</Text>
                                </Item>
                                {/* <Item>
                                    <Icon><LocationOnIcon fontSize="large"/></Icon>
                                    <Text>asdasdasd</Text>
                                </Item> */}
                                <Message>
                                    I hope you found something that piqued your interest here.
                                    We would be very happy yo answer any questions. Do check back for
                                    future updates.
                                </Message>
                            
                        </Column2>
                        </RowCol2>   
                </FormWrapper>
                
            </Form>
            {/* </Main> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I click on my Contact Us link, url changes from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/contact-us` but nothing shows up

There is no error displayed on my console.

Is there something missing out?

Comment: Does your About component work? I would think this would be an issue with react-router-dom

Comment: @J.Cutshall Yes it works perfectly.

Comment: Assuming your custom nav components work correctly, I don't see any overt issues that would cause one specific route not to work. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

This is very logical issue that made me spent hours before i figured out, one have to be careful when writing route configuration

in your `app.jsx` change the order to something like this

```
    <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    <Route path='/contact-us' element={<Contact />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundView />} />
```

This should work because by using the asterics at the top it matches any route because it reads route from top to bottom so you always get the `NotFoundView` component but putting the asterics at the bottom makes sure it matches it last when it doesnt match any

Comment: made the changes, still the same.

Comment: let me check again

Comment: This isn't the case in RRDv6, all routes are now always exactly matched and use path ranking, so the order is irrelevant.